# Play Framework + Mongo Scala Driver + LocalDate

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, localdate

I'm coding services which use case classes with LocalDate property. Previous implementations didn't have any issues with LocalDate codec, but one service is having trouble with the LocalDate codec.
I have this line in my code:

```
private val javaCodecs =
fromCodecs(new LocalDateTimeDateCodec(), new LocalDateDateCodec())
```

And I get this when running tests of the service:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.joda.time.LocalDate.

The LocalDate is `org.joda.time.LocalDate` because of the Play framework JSON serialization. Other services have no issues with this. What can be the problem?

Comment: What's the underlying Java driver version being used here? This has [been present for quite a few releases](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/whats-new/#jsr-310-instant-localdate-localdatetime-support) now. Mind these are `java.time.LocalDate` etc. JSON is not BSON, so anything else needs a mapping between them. I would have thought `org.joda.time.LocalDate` would have abstracted from the `java.time` namespace anyway.

Comment: "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.2.1" - this is the mongo driver, Java is 1.8

Comment: Okay should be java driver `3.6.3`, which is as noted before the patches are introduced. So `2.2.1` is quite old, and `2.5.0` is actually current. I suggest you update your project dependencies.